# how to many to many relationship query in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, relationship

**Brief:**

I use laravel 5.6

I have a problem in **many to many** relation queries.

I have 2 model: Order and Cart

---

**Code:**

Cart Model:

```
class Cart extends Model
{
    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class);
    }
}
```

Order model :

```
class Order extends Model
{
    public function carts(){

        return $this->belongsToMany(Cart::class);
    }
}
```

Cart Migration :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('carts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->integer('price')->nullable();
        $table->integer('pass')->default(0);

    });
}
```

---

**Question:**

How to get orders that their `pass` field are in `Cart = 1` in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, since your Cart has many orders, the relationship should be named "orders" with an s.

You showed only you Cart migration so I cannot guess, but Laravel also expects you to create a "cart-order" pivot table.

If I understood well, you can do what you want like this:

```php
Order::whereHas('carts', function ($query) {
    $query->where('pass', 1);
})->get();
```

You can read more about Eloquent's Many to Many relationships in the Laravel documentation, [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Comment: Thanks . yes I have pivot table . i run your code . but i have error : 
`"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pass' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `orders`.*, `cart_order`.`cart_id` as `pivot_cart_id`, `cart_order`.`order_id` as `pivot_order_id` from `orders` inner join `cart_order` on `orders`.`id` = `cart_order`.`order_id` where `cart_order`.`cart_id` = 1 and `pass` = 1)`

Comment: Verrry Thanks .

Comment: No problem :)
If you want to read more about the the `whereHas()` method, it's detailed [there](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Answer (score 1):

Try Like this,

```
            <?php

            namespace App;

            use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

            class Comment extends Model
            {
                /**
                 * Get all of the owning commentable models.
                 */
                public function commentable()
                {
                    return $this->morphTo();
                }
            }

            class Post extends Model
            {
                /**
                 * Get all of the post's comments.
                 */
                public function comments()
                {
                    return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
                }
            }

            class Video extends Model
            {
                /**
                 * Get all of the video's comments.
                 */
                public function comments()
                {
                    return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
                }
            }
```

//Access like this in your controller 
                $post = App\Post::find(1);

```
            foreach ($post->comments as $comment) {
                //
            }
```

This Link Help you,
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations in that case. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thakns . i use many to many relationship . use order_id & cart_id ??
I wanna get order !!